# Ассемблер. Длина строки. Ассемблерные вставки

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Как найти длину строки используя `repne scasb`, я уже пробовал заносить в al символ `$` но дальше когда пытаюсь в переменную занести `ecx` у меня выдает ошибку

```
__asm
{
    mov ecx, 0FFFFh
    mov al, '$'
    lea edi, text
    repne scasb
    not ecx
    mov counter, ecx
}
cout << counter;
```

Comment: *Cамодостаточности* бы побольше... что такое text?.. не помню специфику MSVC, но сдаётся мне, что там должен быть `mov`, а не `lea`. И если дело на amd64, то лучше использовать соответствующие регистры — иначе в верхней части может остаться мусор.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает? Как объявлен text?

Comment: text массив char, ошибка вылетает на строке с repne scasb

Comment: Ошибка на `repne scasb` скорее всего из-за того, что вы ищете в строке символ доллара, которого там нет, в итоге цикл выходит куда-то за границы разрешенной памяти. Искать нужно нулевой символ, т.к. в Си сторки [нуль-терминированные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нуль-терминированная_строка).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ простой:

```
mov ecx, 0FFFFh
```

неправильно. Должно быть

```
mov ecx, 0FFFFFFFFh
```

т.к. регистр 32-битный.

Ну и потом

```
not ecx
dec ecx
```

Потому что будет учтен и искомый символ

**P.S.**

Ошибка была в том, что в регистр ecx записывалось 16разрядное число (-1), которое в 32разрядном виде превращалось в 65536.
После того, как производилась операция `not` для 32разрядного регистра, его старшие разряды превращали значение в отрицательно (-65536 + str_len)

**P.P.S.**

А почему

```
mov al, '$'
```

а не

```
mov al, '\0'
```

?

**P.P.P.S.**

Я тестировал на таком примере

```
char text[100];
memcpy(text, "myTest", 7);
int counter = 0;

__asm
{
    mov ecx, 0FFFFFFFFh
    mov al, '\0'
    lea edi, text
    repne scasb
    not ecx
    mov counter, ecx
}
```

ответ был 7, т.е. все работало (ну кроме того, что надо было вычесть 1 из результата, чтобы не учитывать символ конца строки)